# Visual Studio reverts line ending setting every time I make a new .cs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Having an issue with VS 2013 where, for some reason, VS reverts the line endings setting (advanced save options >> line endings) back to "current setting". I'm just trying to get it to use CRLF on every file, but the setting gets reverted every time. E.g, every time I want to save a new .cs, I have to explicitly tell it to use CRLF.

Is this by design, a bug, or is there some other setting I've overlooked?

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed, like VS Power Tools?

Comment: Why exactly do you assume that "Current Setting" means "wrong setting"?

Comment: I have `CRLF` by default in my VS2013. I couldn't find `advanced save options >> line endings` in settings.

Comment: @HansPassant Because I use VS to edit code for Unity. Unity complains about inconsistent line endings when I use "current setting".

Comment: VS itself complains when you open a file with inconsistent line endings.  Whatever your problem might be with Unity, you are not close to having found it.  Use a hex viewer to verify your assumptions.

Comment: You're missing my point. I use Unity to make a fresh .cs, then double click it to open it in VS. VS doesn't respect the line endings that Unity makes, since Unity has preset code in it's .cs to by default use UnityEngine and System.Collection. Whenever I save the code, VS uses different line endings than what Unity made when it made the file.